# In linq, how do I take specific parameter out of a list and build new list of different type?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am new to linq. So far I've been primarily using linqTOsql like this: `MyRepository.Mytable.Where(x => x.id == 2)`.

I am wondering how to take a list from that type of query and put a specific parameter into a new simple list like `List<long>`.

So I get my records like this:

```
List<Entry2Cats> e2c = genesisRepository.Entry2Cats.Where( x => x.streamEntryID == id).ToList()
```

And I want to get the category ID paramter for each item in `e2c` so I can move it into a `List<long>`.

Obvisouly, this can be done fairly simply with a `foreach`:

```
        List<Entry2Cats> e2c = genesisRepository.Entry2Cats
                               .Where(x => x.streamEntryID == id)
                               .ToList();
        List<long> e2cCatIDs = new List<long>();

        foreach (Entry2Cats item in e2c)
        {
            e2cCatIDs.Add(item.catID);
        }
```

Can this be done using just linq? If it can, should I even bother with it or is the `foreach` just as good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<long> ids = genesisRepository.Entry2Cats
                 .Where(x => x.streamEntryID == id)
                 .Select(a => a.catID)
                 .ToList();
```

Just use Select to get only the IDs.

Comment: Ah yes... that makes sense that you can string linq statements like that. Is there any benefit (other than concise code) to use this technique rather than the foreach?

Comment: In this specific case I think that other than the more readable and simpler code there aren't any extra benefits.

Comment: Cool. I far prefer this syntax to using a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

List<Long> e2c = genesisRepository.Entry2Cats

```
                           .Where(x => x.streamEntryID == id)
                           .Select(x => x.catID)
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<long> e2cCatIDs = e2c.Select(e => e.catID).ToList();
```

or select directly in the query

```
List<long> e2cCatIDs = (from x in genesisRepository.Entry2Cats
                        where x.streamEntryID == id
                        select x.catID).ToList();
```